# Is real part of a complex differentiable function real differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f=u+i v$ be a complex function. Then the real part $u=u(x,y)$ is a multivariable real-valued function. It is well known that if $f$ is holomorphic at $z=x+iy$, then $u$ is $C^1$ near $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I was wondering if $u$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$ when $f$ is complex-differentiable at a point $z=x+iy.$ Would you give me any comment of it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ and suppose that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$. Let $h=h_1+ih_2 \ne 0$ and $f'(z_0)=a+ib$.

We then have that

$Q(h):= \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)-hf'(z_0)}{|h|} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

An easy computation shows that

$R(h):=Re (Q(h))$ is given by

$R(h)=\frac{u(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2)-u(x_0,y_0)-(h_1a-h_2b)}{|h|}$.

Since $Q(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, we get

$R(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, which shows that $u$ is real differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ with $u_x(x_0,y_0)=a$ and $u_y(x_0,y_0)=-b$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , by Caucht-Rieman  , $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0= (x_0,y_0)$ iff $u,v$ both differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and satisfy the Caucht-Rieman equations

$\dfrac{\partial u}{ \partial x} =\dfrac{\partial v}{ \partial y} ,\dfrac{\partial u}{ \partial y} = -\dfrac{\partial v}{ \partial x}    $

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don’t think your statement is true. If $u,v$ is $C^1$, then $f$ is holomorphic if and only if Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic if there is a neighborhood (open set) that it is differentiable in. @0706

Comment: so $f$ is holomorphic  in the open set $U$ iff $u,v \in C \ ^ 1$ and satisfy C-R equations in each point in some open set $U$

Comment: I agree with you, but you misunderstood my question.

Comment: You asked whether complex-differentiable implies that $u$ is differentiable, didn't you?

Comment: @Liad... Differentiable at a single point,but perhaps not anywhere else, so perhaps not holomorphic anywhere at all.