# Does $f=u+iv$ is $\mathbb R-$differentiable $\iff $ $u$ and $v$ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a theorem that says $f:U\to \mathbb C$ (where $U\subset \mathbb C$ open) is holomorphic on $U$ $\iff$ $f$ is $\mathbb R-$differentiable and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation.

An other theorem I have is $f=u+iv:U\to \mathbb C$ holomorphic $\iff$ $u$ and $v$ are $\mathcal C^1(U)$ and satisfy Cauchy Riemann equation (I guess that $\mathcal C^1(U)$ mean $\mathcal C^1$ where $U$ is seen as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$).

---

**My question :**

**1)** Does it mean that $u$ and $v$ are differentiable on $\mathcal C^1(U)$ doesn't implies that $f$ is $\mathbb R-$ differentiable ? Because in my mind, $f$ is $\mathbb R-$ differentiable means that $F(x,y):=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable, but maybe is not correct.

**2)** Honestly, it's strange for me $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ where $U\subset \mathbb C$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ to say that $u,v\in \mathcal C^1(U)$, because $U\subset \mathbb C$ and $u,v:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$. Can we say that $$\{x+iy\mid x,y\in \mathbb R\}=\{(x,y)\mid x,y,\in\mathbb R \} \ \ ?$$
It's strange, no ?

Comment: $C^1(U)$ is the space of functions with continuous first (partial) derivatives. There is a theorem that says that if a functions has continuous partial derivatives, then it is differentiable. Therefore, the condition that $u,v\in C^1(U)$ gives you that they are differentiable on $U$. That implies that $f$ is also ($\mathbb{R}$-)differentiable on $U$, as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Since you can have differentiable functions with discontinuous partial derivatives, then the statement with $C^1$ is weaker. It is asking more, to give you the same conclusion.

Comment: @user647486: So $f$ being $\mathbb R$ differentiable doesn't mean that $F(x,y):= u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable, right ?

Comment: It does. The thing is that there are two different notions that are called 'differentiable' in the case of $f$. One is being differentiable as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. And there is another that, in this context is better to call 'complex-differentiable', which means that it has complex derivative, but when there is no confusion people just call it also 'differentiable'. The hypotheses on the partial derivatives imply the first notion. The addition of Cauchy-Riemann equations imply the second notion.

Comment: @user647486: At the end, to have $u,v\in \mathcal C^1$ and Cauchy-riemann and $f$ being $\mathbb R-$differentiable and Cauchy-Rieman should be equivalent since both are equivalent to holomorphe function. So how can $u,v\in \mathcal C^1$ be weaker then $f$ being $\mathbb R-$differentiable ? Could you please answer to **2)** (I edited my question). btw, please make an answer and not a comment, because your comment is really an answer :-) (and I'll accept it)

Comment: No, both are not equivalent when considered as statements at a single point. Both of those theorems can be stated as properties at a single point and implying existence of complex derivative at that point. When considered as properties holding on an open set, then yes.

Comment: Yes, $x+iy$ is just another notation for $(x,y)$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810945/269764). Also complex holomorphic functions are infinitely complex differentiable, and since complex differentiability is a strictly stronger condition (in terms of real differentiability, $\mathbb{C}$ differentiability can be worded as being $\mathbb R$-differentiable at $z$, with a derivative matrix that is antisymmetric with constant diagonal) the result follows by breaking a real derivative of $u + iv$ up into derivatives of $u$ and $v$